# Installing biber 2.7

Tags: installation

I am using a software called Texmaker, it uses another program (i think they called it a backend, am i right?) called biber. The current version of biber in my computer is: Biber 1.9. I have tried to download a current version of biber in the webpage http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/ (i am sure it is the correct programme and webpage).

The problem is that Texmaker still recognize the old version (1.9)and not the new one. What should i do? 
Where should i unpackage biber?

Another question, Biber is downloaded in a tar.gz file, so i uncompressed it and it was finished. 
I am not sure if it is wrong or not, i mean, only uncompress the file to install it.
Extra data: The version of linux i have is based on Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian updates packages continuously, but for releases that are already out it takes special care not disrupt and does not update much more than what is required for security purposes. The page https://packages.qa.debian.org/b/biber.html shows that version 2.7 is already available, but only in the next version of Debian which is called "testing". A new release of Debian is expected "real soon" and then what is stable now will be referred to as old stable and today's testing will be the new stable. You may decide to just wait for that upcoming release to then upgrade your complete installation of perform a partial upgrade now as described below.

To get to the new version you could download the .deb package following https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/biber/download and install it with "sudo dpkg -i biber_2.7-2_all.deb". This substitutes your previous version. There is no need to manually decide where to put a Debian package - all previously installed files of that package will be removed and all the files in the .deb file at hand are unpacked at fixed locations. Which files that are you can inspect with the "-c" option, i.e. "sudo dpkg -c biber_2.7-2_all.deb". A program that worked with biber before should now also function with that new version. Should. Just give it a test. If it works then you are done with your update.

The art of assembling a joint release of software packages is the difficulty to avoid side effects. It is common that an upgrade of one packages breaks other packages. But this is not necessarily so and the packages declare any known such dependencies on the versions of other packages. If there are many additional dependencies that you need to co-update with that new version of biber, it may then be preferable to add the download information to stretch to /etc/apt/sources.list (copy the reads jessie or stable now and substitute that with stretch or testing). You then run "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get install biber" to have version 2.7 installed.

Have you installed texmaker also from Debian? That testing release also offers texmaker 4.5 over version 4.3 of the stable distribution features. If your problem was not solved with 4.3 then it may be worthwhile to attempt also an update of texmaker. It is then from the same Debian release as is biber and they should work together since this "togetherness" is what a release is about. You can download the Texmaker .deb file as explained before or with the extended sources.list file use apt-get install texmaker. Again, there is no need to specify any program locations. What is old is removed, the new version of the packages takes it position.

With the new Debian release now so close, not too much should go wrong. But if you are professionally depending on your machine then please try this first on another computer to learn and of course please have backups. Once the biber package was updated, remove or comment out (start the line with the # sign) in /etc/apt/sources.list and run apt-get update again. The newly installed biber package will not be removed again since its version is newer than.

Meta-comment: This site is about programming, not about installing software or distribution-related issues. It may be more appropriate to address this question at https://askubuntu.com, the https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/ mailing list or (my preferred option) some friendly soul in the neighbourhood.